# Is there a way to output a graph to tensorboard using C# SciSharp/TensorFlow.NET

Tags: c#, tensorflow, tensorboard

In C# I have created a tensorflow graph using C# package

SciSharp/TensorFlow.NET

but would like to then view that graph in tensorboard to verify it is as expected.
https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/get_started

To do this I need to create a logfile for tensorboard to read.
I am able to create an instance of the `Tensorflow.Summaries.FileWriter`
C# class as follows.

```
var fw = tf.summary.FileWriter("mylogdirectory" ,mygraph);
```

but that seems to have no `Flush()` method like its python version. How would I get the instance to log something? Do I have to wrap my code in some sort of using statement?

Comment: I found a way to at least ensure the graph looks right but it is hard to interpret:    
     var foo = graph.as_graph_def().ToString();
     Console.WriteLine(foo);